# Passing an Array to Handlebars Custom Helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am trying to pass an array of data to a custom helper with [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars).  I can't get it to work.

I can pass in a string and I can pass in an array to an individual view, but I can't seem to pass in an array to a custom helper.  Here is my code:

**String Passed to Custom Helper (this works)**

```
// app.js
const hbs = expressHandlebars.create({
  extname: 'html',
  helpers: {
    foo: function () {
      return 'FOO!'
    }
})

// views/layout/main.html
<h2>{{ foo }}</h2>

// Result --> FOO! outputed as expected
```

**Passing an Array to an Individual view (this also works)**

```
// controllers/pageControllers.js
exports.getIndexPage = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    testList: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  })
}

// views/index.html
{{#each testList}}
<div>{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}

// Result --> one, two, three outputted as expected
```

**Array Passed to a Custom Helper (this does NOT work)**

```
// app.js
const hbs = expressHandlebars.create({
  extname: 'html',
  helpers: {
    testList2: function () {
      return ['one', 'two', 'three']
    },
  }
})

// views/layout/main.html
{{#each testList2}}
  <div>{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}

// Result --> NOTHING.  No output, no error messages.
```

Do custom helpers not take arrays?  The same code works on an individual view.  The same code works for a string on a custom helper.  It just does not work for an array on a custom helper.

If custom helpers do NOT accept arrays, then how can I get an array of data into my main layout file?  If it does take an array, then what I am doing wrong and how to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation#helpers](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers), -*i'm not using `express-handlebars` myself*.

> A Handlebars helper call is a simple identifier, followed by zero or more parameters (separated by a space)

This means you call it with the first identifier and what follows is to be evaluated.

The helper just takes in data and outputs a manipulated outcome to inject in the view.

Taking in data would look something like `{{ foo exp1 exp2 }}` which translates to `{{foo(exp1,exp2)}}` and the helper would look something like this.

```js
 foo: function (exp1, exp2) {
      return `this is ${exp1} and ${exp2}`
    }
```

It's like invoking a regular function.

***In your first example*** you call `foo()` (the helper function) which takes nothing in but outputs a string, and when activated you get the value return.

***In your second example*** you are using express to render a variable which is loopable on a view. nothing to do with handlebars instance creating. (you are creating basicly an express `res.locals.testList` variable.)

***In your third example*** you try to loop the helper function and not really invoking it. It's trying to do something like this:

```js
for(let v of function() {}) {
 //...
}
```

This will give the error (probably silent in your case,) `is not iterable`

It's seems like you should manipulate the data array inside the helper function and then return a string or an html string (using `Handlebars.Safestring` as mentioned in the docs for escaping html). Then in your view just call it `{{ testList2 }}` which will out put a ready made `HTML` for the structure you were trying to do.

Hope this makes sense.

***That been said, There are more advanced ways of using helpers as mentioned in docs.*** that maybe could fit more for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for your response.  It seems to me that my real question is an Express.js question -- namely, how do I pass data into the layout.

Comment: Bekef ahi. :) This depends on what you are trying to do. `res.render()` is for rendering a template (to HTML) with view variables (what you are trying to do). You could also use other ways of responding an express HTTP request. if you try to send responses as json (`res.json()/res.jsonp()`), or just do a simple redirect with a flash message (`res.redirect`).. If instance creating with scoped helper function is not the issue and you just want to send data from express, stay with `res.render()`. [Hit express response docs for all the options you can do](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953247/7477670

Comment: @Moshe That's not what `app.locals` is for. the right way to send variables to a view is `res.render()`.

Comment: @Moshe I meant with `res.locals`. It goes unstated you are rendering with `res.render()` after `app.locals`. FWIW i answered on a posible solution in the question you linked here.