# How to Handle Global Data in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to build an express.js app and I want to pass some data to my main layout. For example, a list of navigation links that I use on every page. I know how to pass data to an individual view -- for example:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.render('index', { pageTitle: 'Home' });
}
```

But what if I want to pass data to my main layout (as opposed to an individual view).  For example, let's say a list of links that I put in a header navbar that appears on each and every page.

How do I pass that data into my main layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution instead of using `app.locals` will be to set a middleware that runs before each route.

```js
app.use((req,res,next) => {
  res.locals.navLinks = [ 
    // array data
  ];
  next()
});
```

Will run before any HTTP request and will set the navLinks before every route.

this will cause the `navLinks` to be valid only for the request lifetime and won't polute `app.locals`. (which will persist throughout the life of the application).

Comment: BUT i guess you can go with that logic that `Navlinks` won't change throughout the whole app. `app.locals` Is useful for providing helper functions to templates, as well as application-level data.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing -- whether or not to use `app.locals` or middleware.  It seems to me that `navLinks` is somewhere between a particular HTTP request and the 'life of the application'.  It's not related to a particular request, but rather a whole group of requests.  On the other hand, it's not really releavnt to the entire app.  For example, imagine a site with a backend and a front-end.  You could have `frontEndNavLinks` and `backEndNavLinks` -- neither of which need to be available for the whole life of the app.  Still not sure which ooption is better.

Comment: Usually for me (as a best practice) i tend to avoid as much as i can touching global stuff unless necessary - global can mean problems if the app turns complex and things start to mix an get messy. but again, it depends on what you are trying to do. In your case i believe template rendering should be in the scope of the request that asks the rendering rather than stay on the `apps.locals` forever.

Comment: I went with your approach, however, in a different scenario (where I am getting data from a datatbase), it ended up causing an unforeseen problem.  Sometimes, when I refresh the page or go to a different route, my data is lost.  That is, it shows up in `console.log`, but not on the front-end.  I just switched to app.locals and it works fine.  So, for now, my plan is to use res.locals when possible and app.locals as a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can include file of header & footer inside your each `ejs` file

```
<%- include('<path>/header.ejs') %>
<%- include('<path>/footer.ejs') %>
```

This is for `ejs` view engine

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just using global state?

```js
const navbarItems = [{ pageTitle: 'Home' }]

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.render('index', navbarItems);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps me.  I'll have to repeat the same thing for every single route (the about page, the contact page, blog section, etc).  What I want is a way to one time pass through `navbarItems` to my layout template.

Comment: Just add a second route and pass tha `navbarItems` array to that route as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't send vars to the layout in any special way: whatever you send to the template is accessible in the layout.

You have a few options here:

- you populate those vars in every request handler, meaning you'll have to duplicate the call to the function that populates those
- you use some global variables as @garritfra suggested, meaning those vars will be application specific and not request-specific (ie: the same for all the users)
- you [create an express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) where you'll populate those variables and apply it to the routes. I'd say this is the way to go, because that middleware can also use the global variables and can also populate the variables with request-specific info.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using app.locals like this:

```
// app.js
app.locals.navLinks = [ 
  // array data
]
```

I can then use it in my views (including my layout views) as follows:

```
// views/layouts/main.html
{{#each navLinks}}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{title}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This is my backup solution -- see my comment to @fedesc answer for when I use this solution.